# Java insertar valores nulos en BD

Tags: java, mysql, null, localdate

Espero que se encuentren bien, queria pedir ayudar para este proyecto que estoy haciendo, necesito registrar una persona en MySQL desde Java, en un punto del programa se le pregunta al usuario si la persona ha fallecido, si es correcto se ingresa la fecha correspondiente, pero si la persona no ha fallecido quiero insertar un valor nulo en la base de datos, en la tabla de MYSQL esa columna acepta valores nulos, les adjunto el codigo y el error

'''

```
private void registrarArtista() {
        interfaz.imprimirMensaje("Nombre: ");
        String nombre = interfaz.leerTexto();
        interfaz.imprimirMensaje("Primer apellido: ");
        String apellido1 = interfaz.leerTexto();
        interfaz.imprimirMensaje("Nombre artístico: ");
        String nombreArtistico = interfaz.leerTexto();
        interfaz.imprimirMensaje("Pais de origen: ");
        String pais = interfaz.leerTexto();
        interfaz.imprimirMensaje("Edad: ");
        int edad = interfaz.leerNumeros();
        interfaz.imprimirMensaje("Descripción: ");
        String descripcion = interfaz.leerTexto();
        interfaz.imprimirMensaje("Fecha de nacimiento: ");
        String fechaNacimiento = interfaz.leerTexto();
        LocalDate fechaNac = obtenerFecha(fechaNacimiento);
        interfaz.imprimirMensaje("Fallecido? (s/n) ");
        String respuesta = interfaz.leerTexto();
        LocalDate fechaDef = null;
        String fechaDefuncion ="";
        if(respuesta.equalsIgnoreCase("s")){
            interfaz.imprimirMensaje("Fecha de defunción: ");
            fechaDefuncion = interfaz.leerTexto();
            fechaDef = obtenerFecha(fechaDefuncion);

        }
        gestor.registroArtistas(nombre,apellido1,nombreArtistico,pais,edad,descripcion,fechaNac,fechaDef);
        interfaz.imprimirMensaje("Artista registrado");
}
```

'''
Este es el metodo artistaDAO
'''

```
public void registrarArtista(Artista artista){
        try{
            Statement statement = con.createStatement();
            StringBuilder sentence = new StringBuilder("insert into artista (nombreArtista,apellido1,nombreArtistico,pais,fechaNacimiento,fechaDefuncion,edad,descripcion)");
            sentence.append("values ('");
            sentence.append(artista.getNombre());
            sentence.append("','");
            sentence.append(artista.getApellido1());
            sentence.append("','");
            sentence.append(artista.getNombreArtistico());
            sentence.append("','");
            sentence.append(artista.getPaisNacimiento());
            sentence.append("','");
            sentence.append(artista.getFechaNacimiento());
            sentence.append("','");
            sentence.append(artista.getFechaDefuncion());
            sentence.append("',");
            sentence.append(artista.getEdad());
            sentence.append(",'");
            sentence.append(artista.getDescripcion());
            sentence.append("')");
            statement.execute(sentence.toString());
        }catch (SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
```

Este es el error:

> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation:
> Incorrect date value: 'null' for column 'fechaDefuncion' at row 1     at
> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:104)
> at
> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:764)
> at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:648)
> at
> alfaroviquez.david.persistencia.ArtistaDAO.registrarArtista(ArtistaDAO.java:42)
> at
> alfaroviquez.david.bl.logica.Gestor.registroArtistas(Gestor.java:75)
> at
> alfaroviquez.david.controlador.Controlador.registrarArtista(Controlador.java:159)
> at
> alfaroviquez.david.controlador.Controlador.procesarOpcion(Controlador.java:35)
> at
> alfaroviquez.david.controlador.Controlador.ejecutarPrograma(Controlador.java:19)
> at alfaroviquez.david.Main.main(Main.java:9)

Comment: Hola. Creo que tu problema debe estar en el DAO. Debes estar agregando comillas simples ( ' ' ) para armar el INSERT y entonces a la base de datos en lugar de un null le llega un 'null' . Para validar esto que te digo te sugiero que agregues el metodo del DAO al que invocas (registrarArtista)

Comment: Nunca hagas un insert en una base de datos concatenando strings... meterás lo que el usuario haya ingresado, incluso un ; y un nuevo query para seleccionar absolutamente todo de tu tabla de usuarios por ejemplo, potencialmente exponiendo contraseñas a cualquiera que use tu aplicación. Utiliza [prepared statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html), además con eso no tendrás problema con los "null" ni nada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error se especifica aquí:

> MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Incorrect date value: 'null' for
> column

Si planeas insertar valores null, no deberías usar comilla `'` como contenedor ya que en realidad estaría insertando una cadena `'null'` y no el valor `null`, tu campo no aceptaría la cadena `'null'` ya que tiene formato de fecha.

---

Si el objeto ya contiene en las propiedades el valor `'null'` te sugiero realizar lo siguiente, solo usando comillas cuando el valor que tienes en la propiedad es diferente de "null":

```
public void registrarArtista(Artista artista){
        try{
            Statement statement = con.createStatement();
            StringBuilder sentence = new StringBuilder("insert into artista (nombreArtista,apellido1,nombreArtistico,pais,fechaNacimiento,fechaDefuncion,edad,descripcion)");
            sentence.append("values (");
            sentence.append(artista.getNombre().equals("null")?null:"'"+artista.getNombre()+"'");
            sentence.append(",");
            sentence.append(artista.getApellido1().equals("null")?null:"'"+artista.getApellido1()+"'");
            sentence.append(",");
            sentence.append(artista.getNombreArtistico().equals("null")?null:"'"+artista.getNombreArtistico()+"'");
            sentence.append(",");
            sentence.append(artista.getPaisNacimiento().equals("null")?null:"'"+artista.getPaisNacimiento()+"'");
            sentence.append(",");
            sentence.append(artista.getFechaNacimiento().equals("null")?null:"'"+artista.getFechaNacimiento()+"'");
            sentence.append(",");
            sentence.append(artista.getFechaDefuncion().equals("null")?null:"'"+artista.getFechaDefuncion()+"'");
            sentence.append(",");
            sentence.append(artista.getEdad());
            sentence.append(",");
            sentence.append(artista.getDescripcion().equals("null")?null:"'"+artista.getDescripcion()+"'");
            sentence.append(")");
            statement.execute(sentence.toString());
        }catch (SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por su ayuda con esto ya esta corriendo

Answer (score 2):

El problema es como estas insertando ya que tu modificas un string para hacer la consulta y lo que va a hacer es que pone el string `"null"` en lugar de mandar un null de verdad.
Utilizando un preparedstatement lo puedes arreglar y de este modo envías lo que hay en cada atributo a la base de datos en lugar de modificar una sentencia String con la consulta.

```
public void registrarArtista(Artista artista){
    try{
        String INSERT_ARTISTA_SQL="INSERT INTO artista (nombreArtista,apellido1,nombreArtistico,pais,fechaNacimiento,fechaDefuncion,edad,descripcion) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement ps= con.setPreparedStatement(INSERT_ARTISTA_SQL);
        ps.setString(1, artista.getNombre());
        ps.setString(2, artista.getApellido1());
        ps.setString(3, artista.getNombreArtistico());
        ps.setString(4, artista.getPaisNacimiento());
        ps.setDate(5, artista.getFechaNacimiento());
        ps.setDate(6, artista.getFechaDefuncion());
        ps.setString(7, artista.getEdad());
        ps.setString(8, artista.getDescripcion());
        con.execute();
        
       
    }catch (SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

De esta manera puede insertar usando las variables de tu clase.

Comment: Muchas gracias por su ayuda, vieras que me sigue dando el error

Comment: ¿Sigue saliendo el mismo error o otro?

Comment: El problema es que dentro tiene valores "null", no se puede usar aquì ps.setString(7, artista.getEdad());